# Libraries/SDKs for publishing magazine content for the mobile devices

Tags: mobile, desktop-publishing

I'm looking for a framework, library, SDK which can be used for as publishing platform for newspaper or magazine content for the mobile devices.

The expected feature are:

- provides set of API and SDK for further integration with other libraries,
- may support both iOS and Android,
- host the web reader on my own servers,
- embed into an existing website,
- support digital version of the paper (like HTML or PDF content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the most popular platforms:

- [PugPig](https://pugpig.com/) (see: [Documentation and API](https://pugpig.zendesk.com/); [App Design Guide](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pugpigreleases/software/documentation/PPfM-App-UI-Theme-Guide-v1.3.pdf); old code at [GitHub](https://github.com/leethomascook/pugpig))

  It provides suite of products (API, connectors, readers, tools and modules) which can work for a number of use cases including magazines. It provides SDKs for iOS 6+, Android 2.3.3+, Windows 8 (beta) and Web.

  > Pugpig is a framework that allows you to publish beautiful HTML5 magazines, books, newspapers and videos for the iPad, iPhone and more. Pugpig is a hybrid that mixes the best bits of native code with the juiciest cuts of HTML, producing a lovely reading experience whilst allowing you to publish once across all platforms.
- [XCago](http://www.x-cago.com/)

  It is an ECM (Enterprise content management) platform which allows publishers to generate document formats (such as Responsive HTML, Google RePub or Kindle) and RSS from the PDF of the edition. It based on the PugPig solution. It mainly delivers the XML structure which needs further processing in place to convert from the XML into HTML compatible structure.